# is it possible to turn off vdso on glibc side?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, glibc, vdso

I am aware that passing vdso=0 to kernel can turn this feature off, and that the dynamic linker in glibc can automatic detect and use vdso feature from kernel.

Here I met with this problem. There is a RHEL 5.6 box (kernel 2.6.18-238.el5) in my institution where I only have a normal user access, probably suffering from [RHEL bug 673616](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=673616).

As I compile a toolchain of linux-headers-3.9/gcc-4.7.2/glibc-2.17/binutils-2.23 on top of it, gcc bootstrap fails in cc1 in stage2 cannnot be run

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaaaaca6eb in ?? ()
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00002aaaaaaabba0  0x00002aaaaaac3249  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00002aaaaacd29b0  0x00002aaaaace2480  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/usr/lib/libmpc.so.3
0x00002aaaaaef2cd0  0x00002aaaaaf36c08  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4
0x00002aaaab14f280  0x00002aaaab19b658  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/usr/lib/libgmp.so.10
0x00002aaaab3b3060  0x00002aaaab3b3b50  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/lib/libdl.so.2
0x00002aaaab5b87b0  0x00002aaaab5c4bb0  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/usr/lib/libz.so.1
0x00002aaaab7d0e70  0x00002aaaab80f62c  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/lib/libm.so.6
0x00002aaaaba70d40  0x00002aaaabb81aec  Yes (*)     /home/benda/gnto/lib/libc.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

and a simple program

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    struct timeval tim;
    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

get segment fault in the same way if compiled against glibc-2.17 and xgcc from stage1.

Both cc1 and the test program can be run on another running RHEL 5.5 (kernel 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5) with gcc-4.7.2/glibc-2.17/binutils-2.23 as normal user.

I cannot simply upgrade the box to a newer RHEL version, nor could I turn VDSO off via sysctl or proc. The question is, is there a way to compile glibc so that it turns off VDSO unconditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved with a [simple patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.glibc.user/1908) or [here](http://cache-eu.fullusenet.org/gmane.comp.lib.glibc.user/1908.html):

```
Index: work/glibc-2.17/elf/dl-support.c
=====================================================================
--- work.orig/glibc-2.17/elf/dl-support.c
+++ work/glibc-2.17/elf/dl-support.c
@@ -212,16 +212,6 @@ _dl_aux_init (ElfW(auxv_t) *av)
       case AT_HWCAP:
    GLRO(dl_hwcap) = (unsigned long int) av->a_un.a_val;
    break;
-#ifdef NEED_DL_SYSINFO
-      case AT_SYSINFO:
-   GL(dl_sysinfo) = av->a_un.a_val;
-   break;
-#endif
-#if defined NEED_DL_SYSINFO || defined NEED_DL_SYSINFO_DSO
-      case AT_SYSINFO_EHDR:
-   GL(dl_sysinfo_dso) = (void *) av->a_un.a_val;
-   break;
-#endif
       case AT_UID:
    uid ^= av->a_un.a_val;
    seen |= 1;
Index: work/glibc-2.17/elf/setup-vdso.h
=====================================================================
--- work.orig/glibc-2.17/elf/setup-vdso.h
+++ work/glibc-2.17/elf/setup-vdso.h
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ static inline void __attribute__ ((alway
 setup_vdso (struct link_map *main_map __attribute__ ((unused)),
        struct link_map ***first_preload __attribute__ ((unused)))
 {
-#if defined NEED_DL_SYSINFO || defined NEED_DL_SYSINFO_DSO
+#if 0
   if (GLRO(dl_sysinfo_dso) == NULL)
     return;
```

Comment: may I ask how to use the patch file ?

Comment: Sure, apply the patch before compiling glibc, with "patch". http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

Comment: Doesn't answer the question "is it possible to turn off vdso on glibc side?".

Comment: The answer is "yes".